# case staement switch with an intent

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I was wondering if there was a way to do this so it would look better. How can i change this so i could compare integers instead or is there a easier way to do this so i don't have a lot of if statements or should i just try using enum to compare the strings?

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    Intent choiceIntent = getIntent();
    String msg = choiceIntent.getStringExtra("Choice1");

    if (msg.contentEquals("Option1"))
    {           
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1)
        {           
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,Choice3.class);

            intent1.putExtra("Choice2", "Option3");
            startActivityForResult(intent1, 1);

            this.startActivity(intent1);    
        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.button2)
        {       
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,Choice3.class);

            intent1.putExtra("Choice2", "Option4");
            startActivityForResult(intent1, 1);

            this.startActivity(intent1);    
        }   
    }
    else if (msg.contentEquals("Option2"))
    {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1)
        {       

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,Choice3.class);

            intent1.putExtra("Choice2", "Option5");
            startActivityForResult(intent1, 1);

            this.startActivity(intent1);        
        }

        else if (v.getId() == R.id.button2)
        {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,Choice3.class);

            intent1.putExtra("Choice2", "Option6");
            startActivityForResult(intent1, 1);

            this.startActivity(intent1);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it'd be a lot cleaner if you factor out the shared code for every condition. As it currently stands, the code in every if-else statement is identical, except for the extra that gets set to the intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use enums.

```
intent1.putExtra("Choice1", yourEnum.OPTION_3);
```

and to retrieve the value, use

```
choiceIntent.getSerializableExtra("Choice1");
```

That will allow you to use enum for your switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only thing that changes between your statements is the contents of the Intent's extras. I'm also not sure why you do both `startActivityForResult()` and `startActivity()`, but I will assume you know. You can reduce your quadruplicated code by doing the following:

```
public void onClick(View v)  {
    Intent choiceIntent = getIntent();
    String msg = choiceIntent.getStringExtra("Choice1");
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,Choice3.class);

    if (...) {
        intent1.putExtra("Choice2", "Option3");
    }
    // Etc.

    startActivityForResult(intent1, 1);
    this.startActivity(intent1);
}
```

If you really want to use a switch somewhere, you could do a switch on `v.getId()` then do your string comparison.

Comment: This certainly looks better but the problem is that this breaks the logic of the original code (not sure about the coder's intention though).

Comment: did not notice that actually but i guess that is what i get for cut and pasting

Answer (score 0):

i'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve with your code, but i'd use something more like:

1. define Intent-extra keys as constant Strings in the class that needs to understand them
2. use constant ints for values, also in the class that needs to understand them

this way

1. there is no way a typo is going to mess up your intent
2. you can use switch statements easily
3. there is no need to create an extra enum

   ```
   class MyClass {
       public static final String INTENT_KEY_CHOICE_1 = "Choice_1";
       public static final int INTENT_VALUE_OPTION_1 = 1;
       public static final int INTENT_VALUE_OPTION_2 = 2;
       .... 
       public void onClick(View v)  {
          int msg = getIntent().getIntExtra(INTENT_KEY_CHOICE_1);
          Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Choice3.class);
          int intentExtra = INTENT_VALUE_OPTION_3;
          // you can change this easily to a switch statement
          if (msg == INTENT_VALUE_OPTION_1) {
              intentExtra = v.getId() == R.id.button1 ? R.INTENT_VALUE_OPTION_3 : R.INTENT_VALUE_OPTION_4);
          } else if (msg == INTENT_VALUE_OPTION_2) {
              intentExtra = v.getId() == R.id.button1 ? R.INTENT_VALUE_OPTION_4 : R.INTENT_VALUE_OPTION_5);
          }
          intent1.putExtra(INTENT_KEY_CHOICE_2, intentExtra);
          this.startActivity(intent1);
       }
   }

   class Choice3 {
       public static final String INTENT_KEY_CHOICE_2 = "Choice_2";
       public static final int INTENT_VALUE_OPTION_3 = 1;
       public static final int INTENT_VALUE_OPTION_4 = 2;
       public static final int INTENT_VALUE_OPTION_5 = 3;
       public static final int INTENT_VALUE_OPTION_5 = 4;
       ....
   }
   ```